# How can I get the coerced dtype for a list of arrays much like np.asarray()?

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a list of ndarrays which *may* have different dtypes. If they have the same size, I can call np.asarray(list_of_ndarrays) to get a "stacked" ndarray with an appropriate ("larger", coerced) dtype, for instance:

```
[uint16, uint8, uint16, uint8, uint16, uint16, uint16, uint16, int16, uint16] -> int32
```

Now, for lists of arrays with varying sizes, I have written a unify_sizes() method which mangles the arrays into a common size (with different modes such as minimum / maximum size), and this method needs to allocate a resulting buffer with the right dtype.

(How) Can I perform the same type coercion that asarray() does?

I traced the code of asarray() down into PyArray_DiscoverDTypeAndShape(), and I wondered if there was a python frontend for that method?

(I know that I could always first unify sizes into a list, then call np.asarray() on that list, but the arrays can be largish, and I might need to do padding, so I would like to prevent the extra copying if possible.)

Comment: I was going to suggest `np.common_type`, but it requires arrays as inputs, not dtypes, and it's designed for float dtypes.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, that's still a good pointer! In particular, its docstring refers to numpy.mintypecode(), which could be even closer to what I need. EDIT: Alas, mintypecode() seems to be float-only as well, even though its docs don't make that clear.

Comment: or `np.result_type`; or better yet `np.promote_types`

Comment: Great, that's it! (If you want to put result_type() into an answer, I could accept that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of provided functions:

```
In [30]: np.promote_types(*[np.uint8, np.uint16])
Out[30]: dtype('uint16')

In [31]: alist = [np.ones(2,'uint8'), np.ones(3, 'uint16')]
In [32]: np.result_type(*alist)
Out[32]: dtype('uint16')
```

Comment: Thanks! Both seem to work fine for my use case (I have not yet fully understood which one would fit better when).

Answer (score 0):

One way I could think of was to actually call np.asarray() on a list of arrays of shape 1 with the same dtypes as my actual input, but that does not seem to be very elegant.